# Symfony Forms: HTML5 datalist

Tags: html, forms, symfony, doctrine

How can be implemented HTML5 datalist with values from the database (Doctrine)?

Purpose: replace selects with many options to inputs with autocompletion.

Comment: Should be relatively simple. See this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, add your new `FormType` for the field:.

```
<?php
// src/Acme/Form/Type/DatalistType
namespace Acme\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DatalistType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(['choices']);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['choices'] = $options['choices'];
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'datalist';
    }
}
```

In `services.yml`:

```
form.type.datalist_type:
    class: Acme\Form\Type\DatalistType
    tags:
        -  { name: form.type, alias: datalist }
```

Do you have a form theme? If yes, skip to the next step, if no, create a new one in `app/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig` and change your default Twig theme to it:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - ':Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Now define a template for your new field in the form theme:

```
{% block datalist_widget %}
    <input list="{{ id }}_list" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}>
    <datalist id="{{ id }}_list">
        {% for choice in choices %}
            <option value="{{ choice }}"></option>
        {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
{% endblock %}
```

Use your field in `FormType`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('country', DatalistType::class, ['choices' => ['a', 'b']]); 
}
```

Instead of `['a', 'b']` You need to load your choices from DB somehow, I'd suggest passing them in form options as the easiest solution.

Comment: This solution has problem: options values (entities id`s) != text that I want to show in datalist.

Comment: @Yakimun you pass whatever text you want to show to the `choices` option. Datalist doesn't allow values to be different from what a user selects, it's just a way to add autocomplete for the text input.

Answer (score 4):

I spent some time trying to solve this issue, and there is a quite simple solution which solves Konstantin's issue with database access. It is to create a new form type which has EntityType as it's parent.

```
class DatalistType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent() {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

You can then create a new template for this widget:

```
{# views/form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block datalist_widget %}
    <input {{ block('widget_attributes') }} list="{{ form.vars.id }}_list" value="{{ form.vars.value }}" />
    <datalist id="{{ form.vars.id }}_list">
        {% for choice in choices %}
            <option>
                {{ choice.label }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, in the buildForm function of the form you are building, you can add your form element using the DatalistType, and using the EntityType options.

```
$builder->add('fieldName', DatalistType::class ,
        array('required' => false, 
              'label' => 'fieldLabel', 
              'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\EntityName',
              'choice_label' => 'entityField'))
```

Answer (score 3):

In your formType :

```
->add('commerciaux', TextType::class,
            [
                'label'     => 'Apporteur d\'affaire*',
                'attr'      =>
                    [
                        'placeholder'   => 'Apporteur d\'affaire',
                        'list'          => 'bieres'           
                    ]
            ]
        )
```

In your View :

```
                    {{ form_row(formulaire.commerciaux) }}
                    <datalist id="bieres">
                        <option value="Meteor">
                        <option value="Pils">
                        <option value="Kronenbourg">
                        <option value="Grimbergen">
                    </datalist>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your formType :

```
->add('commerciaux', TextType::class,
            [
                'label'     => 'Apporteur d\'affaire*',
                'attr'      =>
                    [
                        'placeholder'   => 'Apporteur d\'affaire',
                        'list'          => 'bieres'           
                    ]
            ]
        )
```

Declare ( controller or View)
'bieres' => $array_bieres

In your View :

```
                    {{ form_row(formulaire.commerciaux) }}
                    <datalist id="bieres">
                       {% for biere in bieres %}
                        <option value="{{ biere }}">
                {% endfor %}
                    </datalist>
```