# Symfony 4, add a text input field inside a ChoiceType

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I want to create a select box with three options of color, and in the third option I would like the user to input whichever he/she likes. How do I add a text input field inside the ChoiceType?

The code looks something like this now:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('shifts', FormType\ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'black' => 0,
            'white' => 1,
            'customized' => 2,
        ],
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'label' => 'entity.user.shift',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It is not nativally supported so you will have to code something specific. You will also need some javascript if you want a good user experience

Comment: ok... thank you! @goto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an HTML datalist element, currently not supported by Symfony forms, but you can create your own:
[Symfony Forms: HTML5 datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355662/symfony-forms-html5-datalist)