# Symfony / Sonata : drop-down with an input field

Tags: forms, symfony, types, sonata

I'm trying do this kind of code but under sonata/symfony framework

```html
<input type="text" name="city" list="cityname">
    <datalist id="cityname">
      <option value="Boston">
      <option value="Cambridge">
      <option value="Exem">
    </datalist
```

i want the propostion comming from the data stored in my database for the entity Service and the field 'serviceName'

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $serviceName;
```

---

```
class ServiceAdmin extends AbstractAdmin


protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper): void
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('serviceName', EntityType::class, [   //here
            'class'        => 'App:Service',
            'choice_label' => 'serviceName',
        ])
        ->add('identifier')
        ->add('password')
        ->add('comment')
    ;
}
```

but i don't find which field i'm supposed to use..

I'm very new in symfony and sonata. If you have any idea tell me and if my question is badly explained forgive me, I can reformulate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony Forms: HTML5 datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355662/symfony-forms-html5-datalist). Also check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667268#55673895) (couldn't suggest as duplicate since the answer is not accepted).

Comment: i didn't solve my probleme but i think the solution is here thanks