# Symfony creating an HTML5 Datalist form element

Tags: php, symfony, html-datalist

I've been trying to create a DataList in my Symfony application by following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355662/symfony-forms-html5-datalist). However, the custom template is never loaded, I just get a textfield and no responses when I attempt to search for strings in the list.

**Below is my modified code of the linked thread above:**

My *src/Form/DataListType* class:

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class DataListType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        // return EntityType::class;
        return TextType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(['choices']);
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'datalist';
    }
}
```

*templates\form\datalist.html.twig*:

```
{% block datalist_widget %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input {{ block("widget_attributes") }} list="{{ id }}_list" class="form-control" />
        <datalist id="{{ id }}_list">
            {% for choice in form.vars.choices %}
                <option value="{{ choice.value  }}">{{ choice.label }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </datalist>   
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My *config/packages/twig.yml*

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'

    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
        - 'form/datalist.html.twig'

    globals:
        sourceFiles: '@App\Service\SourceFile'

when@test:
    twig:
        strict_variables: true
```

The *config/services.yml* is as follows:

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
        
    form.datalist_type:
        class: Acme\Form\DataListType
        tags:
            -  { name: form, alias: datalist }
```

I then add the datalist to the form in a controller by doing the following:

```
...
$builder->add('test', DataListType::class, [
      'choices'  =>  ['one', 'two', 'three']
]);
...
```

As I mentioned above, the custom Twig template never loads and I just get a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is named `DataListType` and not `DatalistType`. I believe the capital letter L is causing your problems. Possible solutions I would think are renaming your class to `DatalistType` or your template block to `{% block data_list_widget %}`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I corrected the class name in services.yaml to DataListType. BUT .... I made an mistake in my original post (apologies). My DataListType class is in src/Form/DataListType but services.yml says form.type.datalist_type and { name: form.type, alias: datalist }. In both instances, I removed .type (I would like to know if that is correct).

Either way, my custom template is still not loading.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This might help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html#registering-your-form-type-extension-as-a-service